# Как перенаправлять часть трафика в openvpn?

Tags: openvpn, tor

Всем привет. У меня имеется сервер опенвпн, я хотел бы чтобы пользователи моего впн могли получить доступ к onion сайтам. То есть, нужно весь *.onion трафик как-то редиректить в тор  сеть, сохраняя возможность доступа к остальным ресурсам через впн.

Comment: Очень просто. Tor открывается в tor-браузере. onoin в обычном. При этом для простоты обычный использует proxy, установленный на openvpn сервере. Если конечно доступ к onion осуществляется через браузер. В более общем случае всё немного (или много) сложней

Comment: Хотелось бы более сложный путь, этот уже отвергнут.